# What happens with the database after app update from app store?

Tags: android

What happens after app upgrade, will it keep the database from previous version or flush out all data?

Comment: An app upgrade does not affect any existing application data. The database will be in exactly the same state it was before the upgrade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All application data (including stored files, SharedPreferences, and SQLite databases) is kept during updates.

Note that the SQLiteOpenHelper also provides an [`onUpgrade()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) method that you can use to upgrade the SQLite database when the database's schema changes. Do not confuse this with application upgrades though!

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I want to use the data from previous version, and not to change the database.